# A cat randomly appears and disapears from the Google Search bar. What is this?

Tags: google-pixel

It looks like the Cheshire cat but I was unable to find anything on the internet about it.

This is a Pixel 2 phone with stock android.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a doodle from Google related to [Sir John Tenniel's 200th birthday](https://www.google.com/doodles/sir-john-tenniels-200th-birthday). This is a **feature** for Google search app widget which you can also disable in Google app settings. You can read about the feature [here](https://9to5google.com/2020/01/20/google-doodle-non-pixel-android-phones/).